# bash: getting rid of '.' and '..' when looping over files that begin with '.' in a folder

Tags: bash, shell, glob

I want to loop over the files that begin with '.' in directory x (x might be any path):

```
$ for file in x/.*
> do
>     echo -n $file" "
> done
x/. x/.. x/..a x/.b
```

What is the best way to get rid of x/., and x/.. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with bash, you can use `GLOBIGNORE`

```
$ ls -1tra
..
.test1
.test
test
.

$ for i in .*; do echo $i;done
.
..
.test
.test1

$ GLOBIGNORE=".:.."
$ for i in .*; do echo $i;done
.test
.test1
```

Comment: This is probably the easiest for a script - for something easier to use here and there on the command-line, see my answer. `extglob` is pretty handy.

Comment: To really answer the question it has to be: GLOBIGNORE="*/.:*/.." (to work outside the current $PWD)

Answer (score 3):

Use the pattern `.{[^.]*,.?*}`, which means any name that starts with `.` followed by a character that isn’t a `.`, or a name that starts with `..` followed by a character.

Also you should write `"$file"` in quotes so names with spaces don’t get broken apart.

Comment: This will fail if for some strange reason there is a file that starts with two periods.

Comment: You'll want to use the new pattern with `nullglob` in case there's no files that match `..?*`.

Answer (score 1):

As another pointed out, *ls -A* excludes . and .. from the listing, not sure how standard it is.

You can also use *find*:

```
find .  -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '.*'
```

Comment: `ls -A` is standard, but the solution with `find` is better (especially if you pair it with `xargs` or `-exec`).

Answer (score 1):

A solution with only globbing, so you don't have to trouble with command substitution and quoting:

```
.!(.|)
```

This requires the extglob shell option to be set:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

This is probably obvious, but the `!()` construct means anything besides one of the patterns listed (delimited by `|`).

Comment: Thank you, depends on the situation, I'll probably use this one too.
--

If only I could select two accepted answers...

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in x/.*; do echo  "$file "; done | grep -v "x/\.\{1,2\} $" | tr -d '\n'
```

The space after `$file` and before `$` in `grep` are important. It makes sure that you have spaces between the listings and that everything is not scrunched up.

or more generically

```
for file in somedir/.*; do echo  "$file "; done | grep -v "\w/\.\{1,2\} $" | tr -d '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ls -A` on Mac OS X.  Check the man page for your implementation for local options.  This command

```
ls -A | grep '^\.'
```

Gave me the list you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Use 2 patterns:
$ echo x/.??* x/.[^.]
- there are other combinations. If using a different one, make sure it would catch "..." and ".a"

(2) Use GLOBIGNORE and exclude the 2 entries:
$ GLOBIGNORE='*/.:*/..'; echo x/.*

(3) Use dotglob with GLOBIGNORE. This will automatically exclude . and .., but now you have to exclude "all the rest":
$ shopt -s dotglob; GLOBIGNORE='*/[^.]*'; echo x/*

Answer (score 0):

for file in x/.{[^.],.?}*

This will match e.g.
.a
.zoo.17
...
..0
..hello

but will not match
.
..
files-not-starting-with-dot

breaking it down...

the {a,b} does an alternation, first matching a, then matching b. So we could also write the above like so:

for file in x/.[^.]* x/..?*

So let's examine the first: .[^.]*
The [^.] is an inverted character class -- without the carat ^ it would match only a dot; the ^ inverts it so it will match any character except dot.
After that is a star, which will match 0 or more characters of any sort
So this pattern .[^.]* will match files with names that
- start with .
- are at least two characters long
- the second character is not .
From the above examples, it matches:
.a
.zoo.17

Now let's examine the second: ..?*
The ? matches any character (but not 0 characters). We're familiar with the star.
So this pattern ..?* will match files with names that
- start with ..
- are at least three characters long
From the above examples, it matches:
...
..0
..hello

Because of the way the alternation works, the files in the first group will all be matched first -- they will not be collated with the files in the second group.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to keep the globbing simple and explicitly remove the unwanted paths:

```
for file in x/.* ; do
    [[ $file == */. || $file == */.. ]] && continue
    echo -n "$file "
done
```